# bootstrap contact form issue

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am following a tutorial on learning bootstrap and I followed the coding exactly as shown in the video, but somehow there is an error that I can't figure out.

When I click on the contact button from the webpage that was created from the html code it will show a contact form that lets you input name, email, and a message.

The problem is that, while in the video, the contact form is bright as compared to the rest of the webpage and lets you click on it and fill in information, but when I try to do this, the contact form is faded/darkened just like the rest of the webpage and when I try to click on it, it will just go away and show me the web page again.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="Contact Form tutorial from BootstrapBay.com">
    <meta name="author" content="BootstrapBay.com">
    <title>BootstrapBay Tutorial</title>
    <link href="../bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BootstrapBay</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>       
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Themes <b class="caret"></b></a>
             <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class="dropdown-header">Admin & Dashboard</li>
                <li><a href="#">Admin 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Admin 2</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Portfolio</li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio 2</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>            
            <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="modal">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
      <h1>Bootstrap Themes</h1>
      <p>BootstrapBay is your #1 source for premium Bootstrap themes & templates</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy Themes</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Sell Themes</a>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src="img/slate.jpg" alt="Slate Bootstrap Admin Theme">
        </a>
        <h3>Slate</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc suscipit convallis nisl, eget rutrum lectus commodo at. Pellentesque mattis justo vel augue pretium euismod. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Fusce eu turpis eros.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">View</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src="img/appi.jpg" alt="Appi Landing Page Template">
        </a>
        <h3>Appi</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc suscipit convallis nisl, eget rutrum lectus commodo at. Pellentesque mattis justo vel augue pretium euismod. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Fusce eu turpis eros.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">View</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src="img/jiggy.jpg" alt="Jiggy Portfolio Theme">
        </a>
        <h3>Jiggy</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc suscipit convallis nisl, eget rutrum lectus commodo at. Pellentesque mattis justo vel augue pretium euismod. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Fusce eu turpis eros.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">View</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  



    <!-- Fixed footer -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-text pull-left">
          <p>© 2014 BootstrapBay.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-text pull-right">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i></a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-2x"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="contact" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h4>Contact<h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="contact-name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact-name" placeholder="First & Last Name">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="contact-email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="contact-email" placeholder="example@domain.com">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="contact-message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <textarea class="form-control" rows="4"></textarea>
               </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple links for same CSS and JS files in your code snipped. It's possible some of them are broken and not being loaded. Use proper links and try again.

your code is fine and is working:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BootstrapBay</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Themes <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="dropdown-header">Admin & Dashboard</li>
            <li><a href="#">Admin 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Admin 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Portfolio</li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio 2</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="modal">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>Bootstrap Themes</h1>
    <p>BootstrapBay is your #1 source for premium Bootstrap themes & templates</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy Themes</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Sell Themes</a>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/slate.jpg" alt="Slate Bootstrap Admin Theme">
      </a>
      <h3>Slate</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc suscipit convallis nisl, eget rutrum lectus commodo at. Pellentesque mattis justo vel augue pretium euismod. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Fusce eu turpis
        eros.
      </p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">View</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/appi.jpg" alt="Appi Landing Page Template">
      </a>
      <h3>Appi</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc suscipit convallis nisl, eget rutrum lectus commodo at. Pellentesque mattis justo vel augue pretium euismod. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Fusce eu turpis
        eros.
      </p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">View</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/jiggy.jpg" alt="Jiggy Portfolio Theme">
      </a>
      <h3>Jiggy</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc suscipit convallis nisl, eget rutrum lectus commodo at. Pellentesque mattis justo vel augue pretium euismod. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Fusce eu turpis
        eros.
      </p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">View</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<!-- Fixed footer -->
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-text pull-left">
      <p>© 2014 BootstrapBay.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-text pull-right">
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-2x"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="contact" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4>Contact<h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="contact-name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact-name" placeholder="First & Last Name">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="contact-email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="contact-email" placeholder="example@domain.com">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="contact-message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <textarea class="form-control" rows="4"></textarea>
               </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



  </body>
</html>
```

Based on the structure, I am guessing that the line `<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>` towards the end of the file **should actually** be `<script src="../bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`.

If that doesn't work, try with the MaxCDN links alone.

Comment: when I change it to <script src="../bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>. It finally gives it the bright color while the rest of the webpage fades in the background. However, the contact form pops up for one second before closing itself, any thoughts on how to fix this? thank you!

Comment: Why move the script tags to the top? Bottom should be preferred. And why the css `links` not inside the `head`, that is invalid html if I am not mistaken...

Comment: you are correct bottom loading JS after CSS is preferable in most cases. It's just how code snippets are made on Stackoverflow, no other reason.

Comment: Using multiple links for same JS file. That might be causing the issue with the contact form since it's working fine in my example snippet.